# Crouton centering custom view and issues with disappearing

Tags: java, android, crouton

Today I changed my Toast to Crouton.
But I had these problems :

**1)Showing Crouton in  center**

**2)Whenever I want to display new Crouton it is displaying previous Crouton again, though previous one hided long ago**

**I want to know if there is better way to solve above problems?? Cause I looked at sample and library but could not find"**

Currently I'm solving these ways

### activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/bigcontainer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >





<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DilmancSRActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

     <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/alternate_view_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" 

    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Creating my custom toast view and centering it horizontally:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/kdrw"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/strnull"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toasttextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### Showing Crouton:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = localdsr.getLayoutInflater();
                        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast, null); 
                        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toasttextView1);
                        text.setText(info);  
                        if (toast != null)
                            toast.cancel();

                        Configuration croutonConfiguration=new Configuration.Builder().setDuration(1500).build();


                    toast=Crouton.make(localdsr, layout ,R.id.alternate_view_group ,croutonConfiguration); 

                    toast.show();
```

For solving the Second  one I had to download library source and use it. .As I do not want to use animations firstly, I disabled animations

```
   //croutonView.startAnimation(crouton.getInAnimation());
```

**issue on removing function that was making things appear again inside**
 `protected void removeCrouton(Crouton crouton)`

```
  //sendMessageDelayed(crouton, Messages.DISPLAY_CROUTON, crouton.getOutAnimation().getDuration());
 //I changed it with below .plus removed crouton.getOutAnimation().getDuration() so it does not throw exception
sendMessage(crouton, Messages.DISPLAY_CROUTON);
```

I believe I am missing something. Hope there is already right way to do those .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making changes within the library itself is not encouraged as it might create issues that only appear within your version of Crouton.

You can change the Animation via `Configuration.Builder.setInAnimation(...)` and `.setOutAnimation(...)`.

The `Configuration` can be re-used and does not have to be created every time you want to show the `Crouton`. The same is valid for your `View`. It does not have to be inflated every time.

Regarding the duplicate display of a Crouton: This behavior is not intended.
The code above looks like it should display a Crouton with the `info` text set. If your `info` text has changed during the display of Croutons it might be a bug within the library. If that is the case, feel free to [report it](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/issues/new).

Comment: yes.I downloaded directly library and made it clean way with setInAnimation. It seems working.previously hided Crouton is not displaying again before second one starts to display. I wanted to know you mentioned that I can use the same View that was inflated. If I will not cancel crouton before adding again with different text will it behave correctly ? Plus As I asked above is there  elegant way to center Crouton. Cause I did not find any methods inside library